# How do I upgrade ruby version for chef in /opt/chef/embedded/bin/ruby?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

When I run chef-client on the node I am getting the error
`activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2`.

But the version installed on the util node is

```
    
        $ /opt/chef/embedded`enter code here`/bin/ruby -v
        ruby 2.1.8p440 (2015-12-16 `enter code here`revision 53160) [x86_64-linux]
```

Answer (score 1):

This ruby installation comes bundled (and tested) with chef-client.
Don't use that installation for other purposes, exactly because of the reason you mentioned.

Have a look at rvm, rbenv or omnibus instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running in Ubuntu or similar, you can simply do this:

```sh
apt-get install  -y --allow-change-held-packages --only-upgrade
```

Of course, you need to be sure your apt is properly pointing to a current repo.